# Restart a USB that gone down in debian9

Tags: linux, debian, usb, usb-device, lsusb

I have a small linux test box that has one fancy usb lan gigabit adapter on it.
This adapter is connected first with a 4 port usb3 hub then to the machine.

machine -> usb3 4port hub -> lan adapter

I've tried also powering the hub externally but the result doesn't change. After some random time this usb lan interface just dies.

Here's the **journalctl** log, the interface is called eth1

```
myhost kernel: usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
myhost kernel: usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
myhost kernel: ax88179_178a 2-1.1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:00:14.0-1.1, ASIX AX88179 
myhost kernel: ax88179_178a 2-1.1:1.0 eth1: Failed to read reg index 0x0002: -19
myhost kernel: ax88179_178a 2-1.1:1.0 eth1: Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
myhost systemd[1]: Stopping ifup for eth1...
myhost kernel: ax88179_178a 2-1.1:1.0 eth1 (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
myhost kernel: ax88179_178a 2-1.1:1.0 eth1 (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0001: -19
myhost kernel: ax88179_178a 2-1.1:1.0 eth1 (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
```

this is instead what happens to the **lsusb** log, before the device not responding:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

after the device not responding:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It appears that the usb3 hub has 2 device address the usb2 and the usb3 part... the usb3 part **Bus 002 Device 002** dies while the **Bus 001 Device 002** still is up.

Rebooting the system fix the problem for another 30 minutes.

However rebooting the system is very annoying.

There's a code that I could call in order to physically disable and re enable the usb hub or the entire usb root without having to reboot the system every 30 min?

I would like to write a cron script to workaround this stuff before changing the piece of hardware that is so unstable.

I've tried also some other solution proposed in other questions but I would like to restart the whole USB root of devices, this could work instead the restart of single device that is not accessible anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `uhubctl` to powerdown and powerup the port.  This should cause the device to reset and that should kernel to redetect it.

eg on my machine this will turn off/on USB port 1-2.2

```
# /usr/sbin/uhubctl -l 1-2 -p 2 -a off  
Current status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0101 power connect []
Sent power off request
New status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0000 off

# uhubctl -l 1-2 -p 2 -a on 
Current status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0000 off
Sent power on request
New status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0101 power connect []
```

Not all USB ports can be controlled that way, but I've used it to re-detect USB devices before.

Working out the correct values for `-l` and `-p can be a bit of trial and error.

You wrote

```
myhost kernel: usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

So I would first try `-l 2-1 -p 1`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, howerver it seems that uhubctl isn't available for Debian 9. There's a way to install it ? I'm not an expert with backports but even with it, it still seems unavailable.

Comment: You could try to build it from source; dunno if something as old as Debian 9 will work, though! https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl

Comment: I understand but in my request was clearly stated I needed it for Debian 9 :( I wonder instead why a thing like the usb power management that is such a core feature waited debian 10 ! in order to be supported... this is insane... is like not having a sound card driver in an os that is so advanced that can handle fiber optics connections and VR devices but miss the very basics... thanks for your support anyway :P